# DB Concept needed for record editing and rollback ability

Tags: sql, sql-server

I love the way SO retains the edits to Q/A's and allows us to roll back if need be.

I'm looking for a DB structure concept on how to implement something similar to this.  Can anyone give any insights?

My current solution is to have two tables like so...

```
Table1  
ID   |   Date   |   UserID
```

.

```
Table2
ID   |   Table1ID   |   UserID   |   Title   |   Details
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this.  You can start by looking at the [MediaWiki schema](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Mediawiki_dbschema.svg/2000px-Mediawiki_dbschema.svg.png).  See in particular the Revision, Page, and Pagecontent tables.

I believe StackOverflow's design is similar.  However, according to this [blog post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/8/5/stack-overflow-architecture.html), the StackOverflow devs ran into scalability issues with part of the design.

Comment: If I'm reading that schema right, then my idea to have two tables should be on the right path then.  **Table1** (`Page`) and **Table2** (`Revision`)

Comment: Also, would you keep a whole entire revision, or some how parse out the changes in order to save space?